# Swift 2 - Real-time JSON feed

Tags: json, xcode, uicollectionview, swift2, real-time

In my app I have a `UICollectionView` that get data from a server and shows cells with an image and user name and comment.

Every time a user posts a new image and comment a new cell is created. Right now, the `UICollectionView` shows the new feed just if I reload the view 2 times.

I was wondering if there is a way to  update the data in the user’s interface as it changes. Without refreshing the app actually like Facebook app does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been updating like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

   var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "callbackFunction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


internal func callbackFunction() {
// do your busines logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this however, every time the collection view is reloaded it goes back to top and refresh. Is there a way to do this without showing that the collection is reloading?

Comment: Before you reload get the current x y position. after you reload replace it with your previous x,y position. this way you can simulate i hope.